# Serialize List<T> of base class with a parent tag

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I seem to be able to find people online who are trying to avoid this behaviour, but I can't seem to get the behaviour I want.

I have a list of Animals and I want to serialize them with different tags for each animal type (as opposed to the default beahviour with attaches attributes)

To get this behaviour, I'm using the following code

```
    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)]
    [XmlElement("Frog", typeof(Frog))]
    [XmlElement("Cat", typeof(Cat))]
    [XmlElement("Dog", typeof(Dog))]
    public List<Animal> lines = new List<Animal>();
```

Which works great, except it flattens the list and I'd prefer it if the xml output was more like
   `<animals>
       <Dog>Bob</Dog>
       <Cat>Fred</Cat>
       <Dog>Mike</Dog>
   </animals>`
with the `<animals>` tag preserved

Comment: You should have separate classes for each animal type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `[XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)]` for `[XmlArrayAttribute(Order=4)]`

You can also specify an `ElementName` parameter in the attribute, which will be the root name, ie: `[XmlArrayAttribute(Order=4, ElementName="animals")]`

**Note: the Order=4 is sepecific to this case. You usually don't need it. **

**EDIT: (thaks to OP comment):**

You also have to change the attributes of the classes of the objects belongin to the list from `[XmlElement]` to `[XmlArrayItem]` [(MSDN doc here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z6zh05s.aspx), like so:

```
[XmlArrayItem("Frog", typeof(Frog))]
[XmlArrayItem("Cat", typeof(Cat))]
[XmlArrayItem("Dog", typeof(Dog))]
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was looking for and probably wouldn't have found for a while, so thanks! For anyone else who comes to this solution though, it's worth adding that you'll also need to change the XmlElements to XmlArrayItems if you use XmlArrayAttribute.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I completely forgot that detail!

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap the list in its own class, and you'll get the XML you expect:

```
public class StackOverflow_10524470
{
    public class Animal
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Dog : Animal { }
    public class Cat : Animal { }
    public class Frog : Animal { }
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4, ElementName = "animals")]
        public Animals animals;
    }
    public class Animals
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)]
        [XmlElement("Frog", typeof(Frog))]
        [XmlElement("Cat", typeof(Cat))]
        [XmlElement("Dog", typeof(Dog))]
        public List<Animal> lines = new List<Animal>();
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        Root root = new Root
        {
            animals = new Animals
            {
                lines = new List<Animal> 
                { 
                    new Dog { Name = "Fido" },
                    new Cat { Name = "Fluffy" },
                    new Frog { Name = "Singer" },
                }
            }
        };
        xs.Serialize(ms, root);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```